# How to move Recyclerview items to the bottom after countdown timer ends?

Tags: android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

[image: Left one is my recyclerview , i want recyclerview like right one]

In my recyclerview their are countdown timer in each item..and when the first item countdown timer ends i want the item at the tom to go straight to bottom. The cycler should go on, till their are items in recylerview. I know how to add countdowntimer. **Please let me know how to do the positioning logic**  Right image is what is required.

This is my adapter class...please let me know if here i have to insert the code..

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.holder> {
// creating variables for our ArrayList and context
private ArrayList<userdet> UserArrayList;
private HomeFragment context;
String timey ;


// creating constructor for our adapter class
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<userdet> UserArrayList, HomeFragment context) {
this.UserArrayList = UserArrayList;
this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(context.getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.onerowforrecview, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
// setting data to our text views from our modal class.
UserDet userDet = UserArrayList.get(position);

holder.ques_name_h.setText(userDet.getCategoryName());
}





long timer = userDet.getCategoryTime().toDate().getTime();
Date today = new Date();

final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long expiryTime = timer - currentTime;


new CountDownTimer(expiryTime, 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;

timey = days+"d, " +hours % 24 + "h left";

holder.ques_time_h.setText(timey);
}

public void onFinish() {
holder.ques_amount_h.setButtonColor(R.color.teal_200);
holder.itemView.setEnabled(false); //makig disclick
holder.ques_time_h.setText("Time up!");






}
}.start();



holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent= new Intent(context.getActivity(),TournamentDetails.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
}

});


}
```

Comment: `notifyItemRangeChanged` you should call After moving the Item . you will get the callback of timer finished thats when you should move theat item to lat position and call `notifyItemRangeChanged(position,size-1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment . But I don't know how to move the item. That's the question only "how to move the item to bottom" . Can you elaborate please ..or show how to achieve this. I don't know that much in advance.

Comment: @ADM i have added my code for adapter class...let me know where should i use notifyItemRangeChanged

Comment: @ADM Please let me know if you can help further